# Set focus back to input after resetting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, focus

I have a form that has an input field that has autofocus with a reset button. When resetting the form, I would like the input set to focus again. Does anyone have a solution?

```
<form>
 <input type="text" name="focus" required class="search-box" autofocus="autofocus" 
placeholder="search items" />
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close-icon" type="reset"></a>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary filtersearch" 
data-id="<?php echo $_POST['search']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span> 
Filter items</button> 
 </form>
```

Comment: Where do I add the script? After the form or below <body>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) Use a reset `button` instead of an anchor element to retain the form-reset behavior of the browser.

B) Bind a `reset` event handler to the form and focus the field that has an `autofocus` attribute. Example: (without jQuery)

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.addEventListener('reset', function(event) {
    var autofocusField = form.querySelector('[autofocus]');
    if(autofocusField instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
        autofocusField.focus();
    }
});
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="focus" required class="search-box" autofocus="autofocus"
           placeholder="search items" />
    <button class="close-icon" type="reset">Reset</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary filtersearch">Filter items</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where do I the script? Below form or below <body>?

Comment: @user3258571 That depends on how do you handle you JavaScript. Usually JS goes into a separate file which is included right before the closing `</body>` tag. But that is out of scope of this answer. Please read some basic tutorials on web development before proceeding, as this is a very basic question.